# IOS: add a parameter to @selector

Tags: ios, xcode, parameters

When I have this line of code

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *downwardGesture = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(dragGestureChanged:)];
```

and this

```
- (void)dragGestureChanged:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer*)gesture{
...
}
```

I want to add at "@selector(dragGestureChanged:)" a parameter that is "(UIScrollView*)scrollView", how can I do?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't directly — `UIGestureRecognizer`s know how to issue a call to a selector that takes one argument only. To be entirely general you'd probably want to be able to pass in a block. Apple haven't built that in but it's fairly easy to add, at least if you're willing to subclass the gesture recognisers you want to get around the issue of adding a new property and cleaning up after it properly without delving deep into the runtime.

So, e.g. (written as I go, unchecked)

```
typedef void (^ recogniserBlock)(UIGestureRecognizer *recogniser);

@interface UILongPressGestureRecognizerWithBlock : UILongPressGestureRecognizer

@property (nonatomic, copy) recogniserBlock block;
- (id)initWithBlock:(recogniserBlock)block;

@end

@implementation UILongPressGestureRecognizerWithBlock
@synthesize block;

- (id)initWithBlock:(recogniserBlock)aBlock
{
    self = [super initWithTarget:self action:@selector(dispatchBlock:)];

    if(self)
    {
         self.block = aBlock;
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)dispatchBlock:(UIGestureRecognizer *)recogniser
{
    block(recogniser);
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    self.block = nil;
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

And then you can just do:

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizerWithBlock alloc] 
        initWithBlock:^(UIGestureRecognizer *recogniser)
        {
            [someObject relevantSelectorWithRecogniser:recogniser 
                      scrollView:relevantScrollView];
        }];
```

Comment: where do i define `someObject` and how do I work with `someObject`?

Comment: Dude, you are a rock star! Love this answer... Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

So the method will look like this:

```
- (void)dragGestureChanged:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer*)gesture
    scrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollview
{
    ...
}
```

The selector will look like this:

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *downwardGesture = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]
    initWithTarget:self action:@selector(dragGestureChanged:scrollView:)];
```

Comment: What trojanfoe wrote in his answer is the correct way to use multiple parameters in a @selector. Please explain in greater detail what you are trying to do, maybe you could use another approach.

Comment: @Fischer The question was about how the selector will look, and nothing to do with the functionality of the gesture recogniser.  Look at the accepted answer for more details about that.