# Copying an UIImageView with its UIPanGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, uiimageview, xcode4.3, uipangesturerecognizer

I have a `UIImageView` object and `UIPanGestureRecognizer` that I want to attach to it. UIPanGestureRecognizer gets move method as a selector. What I want to do is :When I drag the ImageView, I want to make a clone of it and also add a gesture recognizer to it as well. The problem is the move method has only one parameter which is like 
move (`UIPanGestureRecognizer *`)sender

but the problem is the move method only knows about the first imageview object. I tried to create a method like `move:(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender :(UIImageView *)img` to send a different imageview as a second paramater but it throws an error (unrecognized selector ....) in the following code. How can I add a method which has multiple paramaters to the selector?

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer *panRecognizer = [[[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(move:imageView:)] autorelease];
```

Comment: [Take a look at this answer, it might help you with the question regarding passing a parameter.][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8229370/ios-add-a-parameter-to-selector

Answer (score 2):

You could simply get the image view from the gesture recognizer, using its `view` property.